# How do I use test-path in Powershell for a variable property?

Tags: powershell, null

I'd like to use strictmode and check for null status properly. I'm not sure how to do this with test path for variable properties.

```
$MyVariable = [pscustomobject]@{
    cat = $null
    dog = $null
}

$MyVariable.cat = 1

Test-Path variable:\MyVariable
Test-Path variable:\MyVariable.cat
Test-Path variable:\MyVariable.dog
```

This gives the output:

```
True
False
False
```

I'd expect to see this:

```
True
True
False
```

since `$myVariable.cat` is set to a value. How do I check this `$null` state properly with strict mode enabled (`Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To verify a variable's existence and also check if the object, if any, stored as its value has a property with a given name** safely, even with `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` in effect:

```
(Test-Path variable:MyVariable) -and 
  $null -ne $MyVariable -and 
    $MyVariable.psobject.Properties['cat']
```

Note that the above tests the property's *existence*, irrespective of its *value* (which may be `$null`, as in your case).

Accessing a non-`$null` variable's `.psobject.Properties` collection with a property name *never* throws an error, even with `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` (as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.3); if no such property exists, `$null` is returned, which in the context of an `-and` operation evaluates to `$false`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

You can only use variable *names* in `Variable:`drive-based paths passed to `Test-Path`, you cannot refer to the variable's *value* or its properties.

`Test-Path variable:\MyVariable.cat` looks for a variable literally *named* `MyVariable.cat`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
$MyVariable = [pscustomobject]@{
    cat = $null
    dog = $null
}

$MyVariable.cat = 1

if($cat -eq $null){
    Write-Output("null!")
}
else{
    Write-Output("not null!")
}

if($do-eq $null){
    Write-Output("null!")
}
else{
    Write-Output("not null!")
}
if($MyVariable.cat -eq $null){
    Write-Output("null!")
}
else{
    Write-Output("not null!")
}
```

If else statements for all the variables checking if they equal `$null`

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to properties that way.

```
dir variable:\MyVariable | select -expand value

cat dog
--- ---
  1
```